# SiteMap Localization with resoures in different project

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, resources, sitemap

I am developing a web site using ASP.Net 4.0 that is using resources which are located in a separate project file.

In general localization is going fine.  However, the Sitemap is not localizing properly.

Initially, I used Implicit localization naming a resource key, however this broke when the resources were moved to a different project.  We have multiple projects sharing the same resources so a separate resource project makes sense.

For this reason I decided to make the sitemap resources explicit.

The original siteMapNode:

`<siteMapNode url="Account" title="Account" description="showNavigation('Account');">`

using the resource key which worked until the resources were moved out of project:

`<siteMapNode url="Account" title="Account" description="showNavigation('Account');" resourceKey="Account">`

Finally the sitemap node using an explicit resource:
`<siteMapNode url="Account" title="$Namespace:Sitemap, Account" description="showNavigation('Account');">`

Unfortunately using the last sitemap node I literally get `$Namespace:Sitemap, Account` on the Sitemap Display.

Anyone have further suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not modifying the Sitemap file and using the following SiteMapNode

```
<siteMapNode url="Account" title="Account" description="showNavigation('Account');" resourceKey="Account">
```

This was the one I had tried to use to localize the sitemap.

As I had said above this alone does not work.  Looking at the ascx file (the site map was located on a custom control), I noticed we had an event handler on the OnItemDataBound event for each node.

In the ascx file, the menu item text was the following:

```
<%# Eval("Title") %>
```

I replaced this with:

```
<asp:Literal ID="litTitle" runat="server"/>
```

In the event handler I added the following code to localize the title:

```
var node = ((SiteMapNode)e.Item.DataItem);
var litTitle = ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litTitle"));
if (node != null)
{
    litTitle.Text = Sitemap.ResourceManager.GetString(node.ResourceKey, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

In the `GetString()` call the parameter should have been: `node.ResourceKey + ".Title"`.  However, I also took the opportunity to simplify the resource file and removed all the ".Title" suffixes from each key.